# Web service - SOAPui - Receiver Failed to serialize node AXIS2

Tags: web-services, tomcat, soapui, apache-axis, magic-unipaas

Hy Guys,

I have a Web service problem. The used environment: SOAP - TOMCAT+AXIS2 - Gigaspace - Magic XPA 3.3

I have made 2 closely same external xpa program what gives back a blob in the Task's property sheet's Return value. It's "answer" back an XML, the simle different is that the first one make (XPA merge) a smaller (18KB) file (from a Filtered DB source), the bigger is write out the whole record aggregation. (1025KB)

**When the soap UI receives the first one, everything is fine, i got the result XML on SOAP side. The bigger one shows this error:**

With11Endpoint:

```
<soapenv:Fault>
<faultcode>soapenv:**Server**</faultcode>
<faultstring>**Failed to serialize node**</faultstring>
```

With12Endpoint:

```
<soapenv:Fault>
<soapenv:Code>
<soapenv:Value>soapenv:**Receiver**</soapenv:Value>
</soapenv:Code>
<soapenv:Reason>
<soapenv:Text xml:lang="en-US">**Failed to serialize node**</soapenv:Text>
</soapenv:Reason>
```

The only different is the size of files i think so. I have read some option to solve it like BasicHttpBinding's MaxReivedMessageSize and MaxBuffer size, but i could not find them to change values.

Does anyone have experience in this solutions?

Best Regards,
Gábor

Answer (score 0):

For the future. The XML what has sent contained wrong values. Not tipical XML invalid character, instead an  character. So i you have a SOAP error like that, try to Validate your XML file to search an option to solve your problem. ;)